# Wildcard type mismatch vs. Raw Types

Tags: java, generics, wildcard, raw-types

I am running into a problem where a conversion of a raw type to a type parametrized by wildcards results in an exception. 
Raw types are highly discouraged, but alternatives seem unwanted as well.

Consider the following classes:

```
public static abstract class A<T> { 
    T t;
    public abstract void add(T t2);
}
public static class C extends A<Double> {
    @Override public void add(Double t2) { t += t2; }
}
public static class D extends A<String> {
    @Override public void add(String t2) { t.concat(t2); }
}
```

And the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    A<?>[] as = new A[2];
    as[0] = new C();
    as[1] = new D();
    for (A<?> a: as)
        a.add(a.t);      // results in a type mismatch exception
    for (A<?> a: as)
        insideFor(a);    // is not so neat
    for (A a: as)
        a.add(a.t);      // makes use of raw types
}
private static <T> void insideFor(A<T> a) {
    a.add(a.t);
}
```

What should I do?

Comment: What is it you are trying to achieve with your parameterized type? The options you've presented are pretty much all you got.

Comment: If you use `A<?>`, you're essentially saying "an `A` of anything". You can't pass an object into any method that expects that *anything* because you don't know its type.

Comment: Yes, there's no way to make this code safe, because a[0] should only be able to accept Double, and a[1] should only be able to accept String.  There's no type that you can specify for as that will let you make sure that that's what's happening.  This is because something like `A<? extends Object>[] as` doesn't mean that for  each `as[i]` there's some type `T` that extends Object such that as[i] is an A<T>; rather it means that there's some type T that extends Object such that for each as[i], as[i] is an A<T>.  The only such `T` here is `Object`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second way ("is not so neat") is the canonical way of doing it. This is called a *capture helper*. It takes advantage of capture to be able to introduce a "local" type variable. The helper method is usually made `private` so that outside code doesn't have to know it's there.

P.S. `S` is not used anywhere

Comment: Thanks for the response. Indeed it should have been `private`, and `S` was a remnant of a more elaborate example I was working out.